# Piston too tight?

Tags: piston, seized-engine

I am rebuilding a previously seized engine and after sanding the sidewalls of the cylinder and piston with 1500 grit sandpaper (there was absolutely no other choice) The piston requires much force to move in the cylinder (I put the crankshaft on the piston and it did not move) I don't know if that is normal but I suspect it is not.

Is this normal and if not, how can I fix it?

Note 1: It is my first time rebuilding an en engine
Note 2: It is impossible to get any spare parts.

Edit: I partially reassembled the engine and it is quite easy to spin it by spinning the flywheel.

Comment: The piston should not be touching the wall, only the rings make contact. When ststionary anyway. If the piston is a tight fit then is it the correct one?

Comment: What did you do AFTER sanding?  How did you clean the grit out of the cylinder and off the outside of the piston?  Did you measure the piston ring end gap and compare it with the spec?  Did you measure the piston to cylinder clearance and compare it to spec?  Are you sure the cylinder is not warped and now out of round?

Comment: @jwh20 I poured some water and wiped it immediately then I used some dry cloth and after that I poured some oil and cleaned the excess with some more cloth. There is no spec to compare to for any of these things you asked. As I said, I have no experience with engine rebuilding and the only thing I did was visually inspect it. It seemed to be ok

Comment: It would help if you gave more details about what type/model of engine it is and what you know of its history. Has it been sitting around for a long time?

Comment: @Solar Mike the piston doesn't seem to touch the cylinder walls. The last sentence in your comment confused me a bit.If you are asking whether or not the piston is the correct one, it is the original one with sanded sidewalls. If you are saying that what is happening should be happening, are you sure it should be that tight?

Comment: @GdD It is a Ducati Marine DM184HD probably bought between 1975 and 1985 and used very much for more than 40 years. Then it stayed unused for about 5 years and the piston got stuck to the cylinder walls

Comment: I didn't even know Ducati made marine engines! It's an interesting project, although you've picked an especially challenging first one as there's no parts. You need to be prepared that the piston or cylinder may be warped, if so the only resolution is to have the cylinder bored out and a new piston to fit.

Comment: @GdD How can I check if they are warped?

Comment: You need the right tools. I would suggest you post this as a separate question or edit this one to get some answers.

Comment: @GdD ok, I will make some research on that.

Comment: There may be previous questions on the topic on this site, it's worth using the search bar.

Comment: Not warped, check for oval or out of round.

Comment: @Solar Mike do you mean just look at it?

Comment: « Just look at it », ... No, use the proper tools like internal and external vernier or micrometers. If you don’t have them then buy or borrow them.

Comment: Did you lubricator the cylinder walls and piston rings?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes, I probably over-lubricated them if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend (who is a car mechanic) came by and told me that everything is as it should be. I verified that with another friend so i am quite confident that it is ok. I will update once i start the engine.