# Is it ok to seal an oil pan with gasket maker silicone?

Tags: oil-leak, gasket, gasket-maker

I am rebuilding an engine and it is impossible to find any spare parts including gaskets. I am going to use gasket maker and gasket paper for the gaskets but as the oil pan is actually the engine shell, it would be easier and cheaper to use gasket maker for that.
Is the gasket maker going to work or do i have to use pieces of gasket paper connected with silicone?

Comment: Have you fixed the piston issue yet? If not then don’t fit the oil pan: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/84767/10976

Comment: I would use heavy gasket paper and silicon. Olds made the mistake of using only silicone in 1979.  I replaced rocker cover gaskets when they leaked - no problem. But when the intake manifold silicone failed it dumped all the water fast.  Although the factory did not use them , interestingly, the dealer parts had traditional gasket material for the manifold.

Comment: @Solar Mike I thought it would be a good idea to try to crank the engine as i cannot identify the source of the problem

Comment: That seems like a good idea NOT, well when it creates more damage at least you will be able to see it.